# Push Array JSON in NodeJS Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've script fetch data from mongodb to push data in JSON format with a function to get child data:

```
var tree = [];
orgchart.find({ _client: "558f030fd1bdb6ee1859c279", _parent: "root" }, function(err,doc){
  // function get child
  getChild = function(_client, _parent){
    var dj = [];
    orgchart.find({ _client : _client, _parent: _parent }, function(err, doc1){
      var jsonData1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc1));
      if(jsonData1.length > 0){
        for(var j=0; j<jsonData1.length; j++){
          dj.push({ 'text' : '"'+jsonData1[j].name+'"' });
          console.log(jsonData1[j].name);
        }
      }
    });

    return dj;
  };

  var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc));
  if(jsonData.length > 0){
    for(var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
      tree.push({
        'text' : jsonData[i].name,
        'children' : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getChild(jsonData[i]._client, jsonData[i]._id)))
      });
    }
  }

  res.send(tree);
});
```

I got result from Console Log:

```
Level 2A
Level 2B
```

But In JSON data is empty

```
[
 {
  "text": "Level 1",
  "children": []
 },
 {
  "text": "Level 1B",
  "children": []
 }
]
```

I need data like this:

```
[
 {
  "text": "Level 1",
  "children": [{ "text": "Level 2A" }]
 },
 {
  "text": "Level 1B",
  "children": [{ "text": "Level 2B" }]
 }
]
```

What's wrong with my code, I'm newbie in Node JS

Comment: I'm not sure what's specifically causing this issue, but I can't help but wonder why you're using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` everywhere. That's a (probably somewhat inefficient) way to make a deep copy of a structure, and you don't seem to be doing anything that would *need* a deep copy anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using async.map

This is my script:

```
orgchart.find({ _client: "558f030fd1bdb6ee1859c279", _parent: "root" }, function(err, doc){
      if(err){
        callback(err.message);
      }

      async.map(doc,
        // get child from each item
        function(item, callback){
          // child query
          orgchart.find({ _client: item._client, _parent: item._id }, function(err, doc){

            var doc1 = [];
            for(var i=0; i<doc.length; i++){
              doc1.push({ 'level 2': doc[i].name });
            }

            var data = { 'level 1': item.name, 'children': doc1 };

            callback(null, data);
          });  
        },
        // show result
        function(err, results){
          res.send(results);
        }
      );
  });
```

The results is:

```
[
 {
  "level 1": "Level 1",
  "children": [
   {
    "level 2": "Level 2A"
   },
   {
    "level 2": "Level 2B"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "level 1": "Level 1B",
  "children": []
 }
]
```

Thanks to Mr @DevAlien for recommendation use async libray (https://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 0):

I think that doing this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...` is totally unecessary because you are just converting to string and then again to json, so not useful.

Your problem is that getChild executes a query, and it is an async method, so basically what happens is the following

```
var dj = [];
return dj;
```

And this means that you get an `[]` which is exactely what you get.

What you have to do is to use a callback in getChild so that when the query is finished you can call that. In the below code I will add a callback to the function getChild;

```
  getChild = function(_client, _parent, cb){
    var dj = [];
    orgchart.find({ _client : _client, _parent: _parent }, function(err, doc1){
      var jsonData1 = doc1;
      if(jsonData1.length > 0){
        for(var j=0; j<jsonData1.length; j++){
          dj.push({ 'text' : '"'+jsonData1[j].name+'"' });
          cb(null, dj)
        }
      }
    });

    return dj;
  };
```

Now we have to call this function and wait for the result.

```
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc));
  if(jsonData.length > 0){
    for(var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
        getChild(jsonData[i]._client, jsonData[i]._id, function(err, value) {
            tree.push({
                'text' : jsonData[i].name,
                'children' : value
              });
        })

    }
  }
```

The problem here is that the `res.send(tree)` will be most likely empty because of the callbacks. At this point I suggest you using a module calle d `async` which is widely use to handle this problems. What you want to use is `async.forEach`

The last part of code will become like follows:

```
async.forEach(doc, function(jsonData, next) {
        getChild(jsonData[i]._client, jsonData[i]._id, function(err, value) {
            tree.push({
                'text' : jsonData[i].name,
                'children' : value
              });
              next(); //this is needed to know that it must go to the next loop
        })
    }, function(err, val) {
        res.send(tree);
    });
```

And the complete code should like this, I hope it works, because I could not test it:

```
var tree = [];
orgchart.find({ _client: "558f030fd1bdb6ee1859c279", _parent: "root" }, function(err,doc){
    // function get child
    getChild = function(_client, _parent, cb){
        var dj = [];
        orgchart.find({ _client : _client, _parent: _parent }, function(err, doc1){
            var jsonData1 = doc1;
            if(jsonData1.length > 0){
                for(var j=0; j<jsonData1.length; j++){
                    dj.push({ 'text' : '"'+jsonData1[j].name+'"' });
                    cb(null, dj)
                }
            }
        });

        return dj;
    };

    async.forEach(doc, function(jsonData, next) {
        getChild(jsonData[i]._client, jsonData[i]._id, function(err, value) {
            tree.push({
                'text' : jsonData[i].name,
                'children' : value
              });
              next(); //this is needed to know that it must go to the next loop
        })
    }, function(err, val) {
        res.send(tree);
    });
});
```